# D3.js click being blocked by X-XSS-Protection using chrome

Tags: google-chrome, d3.js

My map which is otherwise functioning correctly is not functioning properly in Chrome when I execute the following code:

```
function clicked(d) {
  var x, y, k;
  if (d && centered !== d) {
  console.log("clicked");
  var centroid = path2.centroid(d);
  x = centroid[0];
  y = centroid[1];
  k = 2; // was 4
  centered = d;
 } else {
 console.log("clicked else");
 x = width / 2;
 y = height / 2;
 k = 1;
 centered = null;
 }
```

I get an error that X-XSS-Protection is blocking it because its source code was found within the request.

Another click works correctly and displays a popup window.

What can I do to get this to work in Chrome (and other webkit browsers) ?

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't seem to make any requests or anything like that, so I'm not sure how you're getting that error. Could you post the complete code please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PatriciaW/yK7E3/ contains the code but now I am not getting the XSS error. Chrome is just ignoring the click on the ward map.

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work for me.

Comment: I didn't provide data ... the working map is at http://tcan.ca/content/tcan-members

Comment: Works fine for me (apart from a jquery error when loading the page).

Comment: If you click on an area in the map using Chrome does it zoom in? are you using a Mac or Windows? it works properly for me in Firefox.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47258/discussion-between-patriciaw-and-lars-kotthoff)

Answer (score 0):

According to your query "its source code was found within the request"

It means that you are sending html tags to JS. Which is very much vulnerable. Your website will be vulnerable to DOM based XSS in this case.

For example you are sending this code to your JS

```
<h1>You are doing it wrong</h1>
```

If the attacker tamper's your request and change it to this

```
<script>alert(document.cookie)</script>
```

So in this way, the attacker can steal your cookies.

I prefer you to not send html tags to JS, send values only and if you are sending values to server side then you also must filter the user's input to prevent XSS and SQL Injection etc

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "sending HTML" to my JS.

Comment: If you are sending html tags like <html> <div> etc to server with POST GET or REQUEST method and server is also printing back same input then you are doing it wrong

Comment: I'm using d3.js and I do not knowingly use POSTs. But for some reason I am not getting the error anymore. But the zooming that works in FF does not work in Chrome.